# incorrect output pushing array in Perl

Tags: perl, push

I have a file like this:

```
#Chr or contig Name             #Source #Type   #Start  #End    #Score  #Strand #Phase  #Attributes
313-9640000-9660000:19634:fwd   maker   gene    1978    7195    .       +       .       ID=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10;Name=maker-313-9640000-9660000%253A19634%253Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10
313-9640000-9660000:19634:fwd   maker   mRNA    1978    7195    .       +       .       ID=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1;Name=maker-313-9640000-9660000%253A19634%253Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1;Parent=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10
313-9640000-9660000:19634:fwd   maker   exon    1978    2207    0.48    +       .       Parent=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1
313-9640000-9660000:19634:fwd   maker   exon    3081    3457    0.48    +       .       Parent=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1
313-9640000-9660000:19634:fwd   maker   exon    3535    3700    0.48    +       .       Parent=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1
313-9640000-9660000:19634:fwd   maker   exon    4247    4391    0.48    +       .       ID=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1:exon:2;Parent=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1
313-9640000-9660000:19634:fwd   maker   exon    6766    7195    0.48    +       .       Parent=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1
313-9640000-9660000:19634:fwd   maker   CDS     3267    3457    .       +       0       ID=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1:cds:0;Parent=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1
313-9640000-9660000:19634:fwd   maker   CDS     3535    3700    .       +       .       Parent=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1
313-9640000-9660000:19634:fwd   maker   CDS     4247    4391    .       +       .       ID=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1:cds:2;Parent=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1
313-9640000-9660000:19634:fwd   maker   CDS     6766    7106    .       +       .       ID=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1:cds:3;Parent=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10-mRNA-1
313-9640000-9660000:19634:fwd   maker   gene    7997    13832   .       +       .       ID=augustus_masked-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-abinit-gene-0.1;Name=augustus_masked-313-9640000-9660000%253A19634%253Afwd-abinit-gene-0.1
313-9640000-9660000:19634:fwd   maker   mRNA    7997    13832   .       +       .       ID=augustus_masked-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-abinit-gene-0.1-mRNA-1;Name=augustus_masked-313-9640000-9660000%253A19634%253Afwd-abinit-gene-0.1-mRNA-1;Parent=augustus_masked-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-abinit-gene-0.1
313-9640000-9660000:19634:fwd   maker   exon    7997    8219    0.46    +       .       Parent=augustus_masked-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-abinit-gene-0.1-mRNA-1
313-9640000-9660000:19634:fwd   maker   exon    8284    8942    0.46    +       .       Parent=augustus_masked-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-abinit-gene-0.1-mRNA-1
```

I wanna extract the rows, third column, those with "gene" and put them into an array:

```
while (<>) {
  chomp;
  next if /^\#/;
  my @gff_data = split /\t+/;
  if ($gff_data[2] eq "gene") {
    push(@genes,@gff_data);
  }
}

print @genes[1];
```

However, with that code, my output is "wrong". It gives `maker`, but I'd like it to be

```
313-9640000-9660000:19634:fwd   maker   gene    1978    7195    .       +       .       ID=maker-313-9640000-9660000%3A19634%3Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10;Name=maker-313-9640000-9660000%253A19634%253Afwd-augustus-gene-0.10
```

Any idea?

Thank you guys.

Comment: When you push like that, you are flattening the second array into the first array, basically NOT getting an array within an array, if that was your aim

Comment: I believe @nrathaus has your answer. You'll need to use references: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html Sorry, working with Perl references is a pain. Also, please fix your bracket indentation, it's driving me nuts.

Comment: What is the second location? I'm confused by this part.

Comment: I'm actually surprised your output isn't just `maker`.

Comment: try to replace `print @genes[1];` with: `foreach my $gene (@genes) { $gene[1] }` and in your push do `\@gff_data`

Comment: I'd like to have my desired output by doing this: `print @genes[1];`

Comment: ok, your `@genes[1]` is a 'maker' from the first matching.

Comment: you push into `@genes` split of the string. try do this: 
`push (@genes, join('\t',@gff_data));`

Answer (score 0):

first change `'\t+'` to `' +'` , you have not *tab* char in text

use this code:

```
use Data::Dumper;
while (<>) {
$line=$_;
  chomp;
  next if /^\#/;
  my @gff_data = split / +/;
  if ($gff_data[2] eq "gene") {
    push(@genes,$line);
  }
}

print Dumper(@genes);
```

in your code: the gff_data variable is't the line!! this is a array and when push it you do not push line!

Comment: good one, but try to use `\s+` in this situation. just a point of interest.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand what you want, your code will be something similar to this code:

```
while (<>) {
  chomp;
  next if /^\#/;
  my @gff_data = split /\t+/;
  if ($gff_data[2] eq "gene") {
    # here you want a LINE that have third word 'maker'
    # this can be done by $_ or by join('\t',@gff_data);
    push(@genes,$_);
  }
}

print @genes[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
open (FH, <Filename>);
while (<FH>) {
    next if ($_ =~ /^#/);
    push (@genes, $_) if ($_ =~ /.*?\s+.*?\s+gene/is);
}
print Dumper \@genes;
```